# Unzip file with expo in react native

Tags: react-native, expo, zip

I use expo to run my IOS and Android applications.
I want to use the react-native-zip-archive lib but as soon as I try to run my code I get this error

[TypeError: Cannot read property 'unzip' of null]

Does anyone have a solution?

```
const downloadAndExtractZip = async () => {
  try {
    // Définition des variables
    const zipUrl = "URL_DU_SITE";
    const fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "Chupaca.zip";
    const destinationDirectory = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'maps/';
    const charset = "UTF-8";

    // Vérification de l'existence du fichier ZIP
    const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(fileUri);

    if (fileInfo.exists) {
      const files = await FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory);
      console.log('Contenu du répertoire :', files);
    }

    // Téléchargement du fichier ZIP
    const downloadFile = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(zipUrl, fileUri);

    if (downloadFile.status === 200) {
      console.log('Téléchargement du fichier ZIP terminé.')

      // Extraction du fichier ZIP
      console.log('Extraction du fichier ZIP...' + fileUri)
      await unzip(fileUri, destinationDirectory, charset)
      console.log('Extraction du ZIP terminée.');
    } else {
      console.log('Erreur lors du téléchargement du fichier ZIP.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erreur lors de la récupération du fichier ZIP :', error);
  }
  ;
};

// Utilisation de la fonction pour télécharger et extraire le fichier ZIP
downloadAndExtractZip();
```

I've tried several libraries but none of them work.